# Can't get jQuery autoComplete to filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

Hi I'm trying to get jQuery's autoComplete ui to work.

Currently I have a asp.net TextBox and I'm calling a webservice and chaining the results of this list to the textbox. The webservice that I'm calling gets an unfiltered list of results from an SQL database.

```
public List<string> getAutoCompleteList() {
    DataSet dsAutoList = getAutoList();
    DataTable dtAutoList = dsAutoList.Tables[0];
    List<string> lstTitles = new List<string>();
    foreach (DataRow drAutoList in dtAutoList.Rows)
    {
        //zAutolist = zAutolist + drAutoList["course_title"].ToString();
        lstTitles.Add(drAutoList["course_title"].ToString());
    }

    return lstTitles;
}
```

The javascripts that assigns this list to the textbox is (on load)

```
function autoComplete() {
    $(".txtSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/webservice/wsJQueryAutoComplete.asmx/getAutoCompleteList",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                success: function(data) {
                    response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
                        return { value: item }
                    }))
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3    // MINIMUM 3 CHARACTER TO START WITH.
    });
}
```

All is well as in if I start typing in the text box then the results appears but the problem is that the list of results isn't filtered based upon what I type in the search box it just shows every item in the list and doesn't filter it regardless of what I type in.

Could someone spare a few minutes and lemme know what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks,
Craig

Comment: you are not sending the data which is typed in textbox to your ajax call on the basis of which you can get the filtered list, instead, its returning the whole list

Comment: when you sent there request to server send the searched term also to server like `data: {term: request.term}` and in the server implement the filter logic

Comment: @Deepanshu The only call that I want to make to the server is to get the complete list of all available titles for the user. I thought that the jquery autocomplete function would filter this list itself based on what the user types into the search box without having to go back to the server time and time again. Is this not the case?

Comment: means if you enter even a random string like xyz, even then it displays whole list ?

Comment: Yes, as soon as I type 3 or more characters the list appears completely unfiltered

Comment: You can pass two different things to the source property: Either a function that returns the list items for the given term (as you did) or an array of all possible items that will be automatically filtered by jQuery. So you could simply load the data with the page (or async) and then set it as the source.

Comment: pass parameter to getAutoCompleteList(String param) and filter your data with that parameter on server side.You are sending same data so its not filtering it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not doing the filtering on the server, I;m trying to get the filtering to kick in on the client

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to dynamically populate the search terms based on input, you must populate your search items in an array prior to initialising the autocomplete, i.e. move the $.ajax call outside of the call to autocomplete:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/webservice/wsJQueryAutoComplete.asmx/getAutoCompleteList",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    // Changed here:
    success: function(data) {
        $(".txtSearch").autocomplete({
             source: data.d
        });
    }
});
```

So, when initialising the jquery autocomplete, you are passing a pre-populated array as the source parameter which will cause the filter to act on the static list.

```
$(".txtSearch").autocomplete({
    source: prepopulatedList
});
```